# C/C++ Makefile: How to build dependencies between with .c files and object files in other directories?

Tags: c++, object, makefile, dependencies

here is my .c and .o files hierarchy:

```
---/src/IRBuild/main.c
                func1.c
                func2.c
---/inclue/main.h
           func1.h
           func2.h

---/build/IRBuild/main.o
                  func1.o
                  func2.o 
                  irbuild
```

Below is my Makefile under ~/src/IRBuild/, I had build compile dependency with .c and .h files, which means whenever .c or .h files are changed. "make" will rebuild the object files. BUT because I output .o files to ~/build/IRBuild/, instead of current directory, "make" will rebuild all the .o files everytime I do make.

How should I build dependencies with .o files in other directories? Only re-compile the particular file when it's .c, .h, or .o file changed?

Stuck here for two days, thanks a lot!

```html
   EXE=irbuild

# G++ as default compiler
CC=g++

# Compile time flags
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall

# Library paths in addition to /usr/lib
LFLAGS=-std=c++0x

# Libraries to link into executable:
#LIBS = -lmylib -lm

# Include files directory other than /usr/include
INCLUDES=-I../../include/

SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ=$(SRC:.cpp=.o)
DEP=$(OBJ:.o=.d)
BUILD=../../build/IRBuild
TESTS=../../tests/

OBJS :=$(foreach obj, $(OBJ), $(BUILD)/$(obj))

.PHONY: depend clean

all: $(EXE)
        cp $(EXE) $(TESTS)
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(EXE) $(OBJS)

.cpp.o:
        $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $(BUILD)/$@

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(DEP) $(EXE)

depend: .depend
.depend: $(SRC)
        rm -f ./.depend
        $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -MM $^ -MF ./.depend;
include .depend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are violating rule 2 from `http://make.mad-scientist.net/rules.html` which is why it rebuilds them all the time it thinks they don't exist. (Listing `$(OBJ)` in the prereqs and `$(OBJS)` in the recipe linking line is also a bit of a makefile "smell".)

You need to use a rule that correctly maps from your target files to their prerequisites.

Either manually or using `vpath`.

There are a number of ways to make the manual method work depending on how much effort you want to put in to setting things up. The `vpath` method is likely to be a fair bit easier.

Using `vpath` should just require using `$(OBJS)` as the `$(EXE)` prereqs and then adding `vpath %.cpp .` and `vpath %.h ../../include` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you Etan, do you mean this rule violate rule 2?
`code `.cpp.o:
        $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $(BUILD)/$@
`code`
How to change it?? if I remove $(BUILD), the $@ just generate object file itself, no path info in it.

And vpath is dealing with prerequirement right? But I am talking about dependency, how can I build dependencies with .o files in other directory?

Comment: Yes, that recipe line. Your recipe's need to generate *exactly* `$@` not a variation of it. Correct, `vpath` is for prereqs. That's why when I mentioned that I said you use `$(OBJS)` as the prereqs since that has the `$(BUILD)` path in the filenames and then you let `vpath` find the matching sources for those object files.

Comment: Etan, it works! 
I add "vpath %.o ../../build/IRBuild", then it works! Thank you! I don't have 15 reputations, so I can't vote you up.

Comment: If you drop `$(BUILD)` from `$@` in that suffix rule and add that `vpath` directive I suppose it might work. I wouldn't do it that way but if it works it works. You should be able to accept the answer even if you can't upvote it though.